# AWS Data Pipeline - RedshiftCopyActvity - Redshift to S3 - Set to pipe delimited

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I've set up a Data Pipeline that dumps a table to S3 file every four hours. Everything is working as expected. The only issue is that this file is used to load another redshift table that is looking for a pipe delimited S3 file to populate. I do not have access to the Serde parameters of this table, thus I need to force the output S3 file to be Pipe ("|") delimited.

The following is the JSON used to create the pipeline:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "subnetId": "subnet",
      "resourceRole": "DefaultResourceRole",
      "role": "DefaultRole",
      "securityGroupIds": "someid",
      "instanceType": "m3.large",
      "name": "DefaultResource",
      "keyPair": "blah",
      "id": "ResourceId",
      "type": "Ec2Resource",
      "terminateAfter": "15 Minutes"
    },
    {
      "databaseName": "blah",
      "*password": "blahwithsymbols",
      "name": "DefaultDatabase",
      "id": "DatabaseId",
      "clusterId": "production",
      "type": "RedshiftDatabase",
      "username": "blahblah"
    },
    {
      "period": "4 Hours",
      "name": "Every 4 hours",
      "id": "DefaultSchedule",
      "type": "Schedule",
      "startAt": "FIRST_ACTIVATION_DATE_TIME"
    },
    {
      "failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "resourceRole": "ResourceRole",
      "role": "Role",
      "pipelineLogUri": "s3://logs.blah.blah",
      "scheduleType": "cron",
      "name": "Default",
      "id": "Default"
    },  
    {
      "output": {
        "ref": "S3DataNodeId"
      },
      "input": {
        "ref": "RedshiftDataNodeId"
      },
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "onSuccess": {
        "ref": "SuccessNotify"
      },
      "onFail": {
        "ref": "FailureNotify"
      },
      "name": "Copy",
      "id": "RedshiftCopyActivityId",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "ResourceId"
      },
      "type": "RedshiftCopyActivity",
      "insertMode": "TRUNCATE"      
    },
    {
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "database": {
        "ref": "DatabaseId"
      },
      "name": "DefaultRedshiftDataNode",
      "id": "RedshiftDataNodeId",
      "type": "RedshiftDataNode",
      "tableName": "blah"
    },
    {
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "directoryPath": "s3://blah.com/blah/#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY')}/#{month(@scheduledStartTime)}",
      "name": "DefaultS3DataNode",
      "id": "S3DataNodeId",
      "type": "S3DataNode"
    },
    {
      "subject": "Load SUCCESS: #{node.@scheduledStartTime}",
      "name": "Load Success SNS",
      "id": "SuccessNotify",
      "message": "Successfully ran RedshiftCopyActivity #{node.name}.",
      "type": "SnsAlarm",
      "topicArn": "-"
    },  
    {
      "subject": "Load FAILURE: #{node.@scheduledStartTime}",
      "name": "Failed SNS",
      "id": "FailureNotify",
      "message": "FAILED: RedshiftCopyActivity #{node.name}.",
      "type": "SnsAlarm",
      "topicArn": "blah"
    }  
  ],
  "parameters": []
}
```

Will I need to create a Data Format section for the delimiter or is there something like a "delimiter" tag for the s3 node?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have given up with data pipeline a long time ago due to its complexity / inflexibility / reliability. By the lack of responses to your question perhaps others have too. You could set up a s3 trigger hat initiates a lambda to convert the "," to "|" . You could use DMS (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html#CHAP_Target.S3.Configuring) or redshift unload https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Comment: Fortunately, I did figure this out eventually. It took me some deep diving, but I found the solution on a message forum. I'll post the answer shortly.